# Remove adjacent duplicates in a string in C

Tags: c, c-strings

How to remove all adjacent duplicates in a string in C. say for example..if "caaabbcdd" is the given string then it should remove sequentially as

```
 1. cbbcdd

 2. ccdd

 3. dd
```

thus an empty string is returned in the end. Time complexity can be O(n^2) for starting.Can anyone help.

so far this i what i have done

```
void recursiven2(char *str)
{
int i,j,k,len;
    len=strlen(str);
    for(i=0;i<len-1;i++)
    {
    if(str[i]==str[i+1])
    {
        for(j=i;j<len-2;j++)
            str[j]=str[j+2];
        str[j]='\0';
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: What have you managed to achieve, so far? Post your code.

Comment: void find(char *str)
    {
 int i,j,k,len;
  len=strlen(str);
  for(i=0;i<len-1;i++)
  {
  if(str[i]==str[i+1])
  {
   for(j=i;j<len-2;j++)
    str[j]=str[j+2];
   str[j]='\0';
  }
  }
 
    }

Comment: And does it work/not work? Where are you stuck?

Comment: no the code doesn't giving the proper output..i am missing some logic

Comment: I believe this can be achieved in `O(n)` with a single stack.

Comment: @phoeagon yes may be we can ,but i want to the logic for solving in O(n^2).

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursively-remove-adjacent-duplicates-given-string/). It has a very nice explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is close, but not quite.

It's easier to think about this in terms of "if this character is the same as the previous, drop it". Your code is more like "if this character is the same as the next", if you see the difference.

Also, [`memmove()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memmove) just loves this.

Perhaps something like:

```
void compress(char *str)
{
  size_t len = strlen(str);

  if(len <= 1)
    return;

  for(size_t i = 1; i < len; )
  {
    if(str[i] == str[i - 1])
    {
      memmove(&str[i], &str[i + 1], (len - (i + 1) + 1);
      --len;
    }
    else
      ++i;
  }
}
```

There might be an [obi-wan error](http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/obi-wan+error) (or two!) in the above, I haven't tested it.

Comment: your code is not producing right output...for string "ccaaabbdd" returning string should be empty...but in your case it is "cabd".

Answer (score 0):

```
string removeDuplicates(string s) {
    int done=0;
    while(done==0)
    {
        int check=0;
        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
    {
        if(s[i]==s[i+1])
        {
            s.erase(i,2);
            check=1;
        }
        
    };
        if(check==0)
        {
            done=1;
        }
    
        
    }
    return s;
        
    
}
```