# Need to write a C Program to remove repeated characters adjacent to each other

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, char

I need to remove only the repeated characters that are adjacent to each other.

Example: if the input is `"heeellooo wooorllldd"`, the output should be `"helo world"`. The output I am currently getting is `"helo wrd"`.

This is the code i have.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{
    char str[]="heeello wooorld";
    redundant(str);
}

void redundant(char *str)
{
    int check=0;
    int i,j;
    char ch;

    while(str[check]) 
    {
        ch = str[check];
        i = j = check + 1;

        while(str[i]) 
        {
            if(str[i] != ch) 
            {
                str[j] = str[i];
                j++; 
            }

            i++; 
        }

        str[j]='\0';
        check++;
    }

    printf("String after removing duplicates : %s\n",str);
}
```

Comment: If you've been working on this for a while, then show the code you've got so far.

Comment: `I have been working on this for a while`  Then you must have some code to share with us.

Comment: Check at least [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20049661/remove-adjacent-duplicates-in-a-string-in-c) and [2](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursively-remove-adjacent-duplicates-given-string/)

Comment: @RickS  I have added the code. Please have a look at it. That code is for removing the repeated characters, but I need to remove the characters that are repeated adjacent to each other.

Comment: It looks like you are not checking for how many words there are in the string (separated by spaces). You will need to have the while loop stop searching for repeated characters when it reaches a delimited character (space in this case) or the end of the string so the while loop can start over on the next word.

Comment: Without looking at the code, I notice that the second series each of `o` and `l` have been removed wrongly, so I guess you need to reset a counter or a flag somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was looking for a minimalistic solution. Just for fun.

```
void redundant(char *str) {
    int lastch = -1;         /* last read character */
    char* inpp = str;        /* pointer to input location */
    char* outp = str;        /* pointer to output location */
    while (*inpp != '\0') {
        if (*inpp != lastch) {
            *outp++ = lastch = *inpp;
        }
        inpp++;
    }
    *outp = '\0';
    printf("String after removing duplicates : %s\n", str);
}
```

Comment: `for(size_t i=0,j=0; (s[j]=s[i]); j+=s[i+1]!=s[i], i++);`

Answer (score 2):

Whats happening is that your in code a character is taken and then the entire string is checked if the same character is present again .If it is present it is deleted .Therefore your program has only one copy of each character instead of deleting adjacent same characters.

Try this code instead :

```
#include<stdio.h>    
#include<string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
 #include <conio.h>
void redundant(char *);
main()
{
 clrscr();
 char str[]="heeello wooorld";
 redundant(str);
 getch();
 }

void redundant(char *str)
  {
 int check=0;
 int i,j;
 char ch;
 while(str[check]) {
 j=i=check;
 ch= str[check+1];
 if(str[check] == ch)
   {
    i++;
   check--;
    }
 while(str[i]) {
 str[j] = str[i];
 j++;
 i++;
 }
 str[j]='\0';   
 check++;
 }
 printf("String after removing duplicates : %s\n",str);
}
```

In my code i check if the adjacent character is same or not.If yes I copy the entire string from the next to next position instead.

You could have shortened code by using strcat function as shown :

```
void redundant(char *str)
  {
  int check=0;
  while(str[check]) {
  if(str[check] == str[check+1])
    {
     str[check+1]='\0';
     strcat(str,str+check+2);
     check--;
     }
     check++;
   }
```

Comment: Thanks Sourav. It worked. I have been trying to do the same but was couldn't get that right. Thanks again. I really appreciate it.

Comment: You could have skipped the 2nd while loop using strcat function thus hugely reducing code length. @Vinay